Does TransformedRegion work with discontinuous functions?
The command
Region[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], 
Function[p, {Piecewise[{{2*p[[1]], p[[1]] < 1/2}, {1/2*p[[1]], 
p[[1]] >= 1/2}}], p[[2]]}]]]

quits a fresh kernel on my comp in a dozen of minutes. The command
Region[TransformedRegion[Rectangle[], Function[p, {Piecewise[{{2*p[[1]], p[[1]] < 1/2}, 
{3*p[[1]] - 1/2,p[[1]] >= 1/2}}], p[[2]]}]]]

, where the map is continuous, works well.
So the question arises: does TransformedRegion handle discontinuous maps? I don't find the answer in the documentation, I also didn't obtain any explanation from Wolfram Technical Support ([CASE:4541910]  on 2020-05-02 ).

Do you want to plot the region or only want to do other thing? For example, Area work.  TransformedRegion[Rectangle[],   Function[   p, {Piecewise[{{2*p[[1]], p[[1]] < 1/2}, {1/2*p[[1]],        p[[1]] >= 1/2}}], p[[2]]}]]//Area

@cvgmt:Thank you for your valuable comment. I want to plot the region and I know a workaround for this toy case : to split Rectangle[] into Rectangle[{0,0},{1/2,1}] and Rectangle[{1/2,0},{1,1}]. There are more complex cases and one should know whether discontinuous maps are supported by TransformedRegion.


I have test the version 11.3,12.2,12.3,13.3.1,14.0,14.1,none of them work for the discontinous case.

To plot the region,we have to use ParametricPlot.


rectangle = Rectangle[];
f = Function[
   p, {Piecewise[{{2*p[[1]], p[[1]] < 1/2}, {1/2*p[[1]], 
       p[[1]] >= 1/2}}], p[[2]]}];
{ParametricPlot[f[{x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, y} ∈ rectangle], 
 ParametricPlot[f[{x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, y} ∈ rectangle, 
  PlotStyle -> Opacity[1]]}



+1. Thank you for a one more workaround. In my opinion, only ParametricPlot[f[{x, y}] // Evaluate, {x, y} ∈ rectangle] is more exact.

Moreover, I have decided to accept your answer since your approach need not any partition.
